# Checking in a file through Jenkins without user credentials

Tags: shell, jenkins, credentials

I am trying to checkin/commit and push a file to repository. In order to do that Ill be needing users credentials. Is there an environment variable that can provide a user credentials? Or do I have to manually ask a user to provide their credentials? and do I have to use shell script to push the file or is there another way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a git repo?
When you are a normal user, and checkout git code with a ssh connection, you can setup the environment with keys in ${HOME}/.ssh in such a way that you do not need the credentials for every git pull/push.
So when you want Jenkins to auto-generate some files to be checked in, and you want to be able to track the changes with `git log` ("Which idiot wrote that line?"), you should make a special user (somebody like jenkins).
When the file is generated, I would use a script for

```
cd workspace
git pull
my_generate.sh
git -am "Generated code" newfile
git push
```